# Check if number is 32 bit unsigned without warnings?

Tags: c#, validation, input

Here's a puzzle, I am receiving a number in the form of a string. I need to check this input by making sure it is a valid unsigned 32 bit number (negatives should be rejected). The catch is it's for a '0 warnings' project, so this doesn't work:

```
    try
    {
        uint input = Convert.ToUInt32(textBoxSN.Text.ToString());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //error handling
    }
```

because I get a warning "the variable 'ex' was declared but never used." And I have no useful way to use the variable. If write a line using 'ex' that has no effect I'll then get a warning for THAT.

Furthermore, the way my program is structured, I don't want to do anything with the variable 'input' in this function, just validate. So I also get the warning that 'input' was declared but never used. Any ideas? Not super important just an interesting problem in C#.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `textBoxSN.Text` is not an `Int32`?

Comment: [UInt32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8). Then you don't need to bother with any of the exception stuff or unused variables.

Comment: Something like print a message to the console when the form data is sent.

Comment: Also, `Text` is already a `string`...you don't need to call `ToString()` on it...

Answer (score 4):

Unless I am missing something here, just use `UInt32.TryParse`:

```
UInt32 ui;

if (UInt32.TryParse("100", out ui))
    Console.WriteLine("100: Valid");
else
    Console.WriteLine("100: Not Valid");

if (UInt32.TryParse("-100", out ui))
    Console.WriteLine("-100: Valid");
else
    Console.WriteLine("-100: Not Valid");
```

Output:

```
100: Valid
-100: Not Valid
```

No compiler warnings shown.

In your case you would use it like so:

```
UInt32 input;

if (UInt32.TryParse(textBoxSN.Text, out input))
{
    // Is valid
}
else
{
    // Is not valid
}
```

**EDIT**

Following comment from OP about not actually wanting to consume the output of the `TryParse` statement:

```
if (UInt32.TryParse("100", out _))
    ...
```

This will discard the result of the output parameter and remove any compiler warning if you are not using a variable to store the output.

In your case if you wanted to handle non-valid values only, you could do something like:

```
if (!UInt32.TryParse(textBoxSN.Text, out _))
{
    // Is not valid
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you got no compiler warnings because you used 'input' to print to the console. I don't use 'input' in this function so I get a warning on it.

Comment: @Jedediah Please see the update using `out _` which discards the result stored in the output parameter.

Comment: @Jedediah please reconsider “I don't use 'input' in this function”; at least use it in the error message. “1e+3 is not a valid integer” is a much more useful message than “Not valid”, especially if there are other things that can also make your input not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just write a simple method that takes a `string` and returns a `bool` that reflects whether or not the input was a valid `uint`. Note we use [`uint.TryParse`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwio6oeUy7LiAhW0On0KHetXBgAQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.uint32.tryparse&usg=AOvVaw0xlbBwry5aVBfhftWeriTT) here, which returns a `bool` indicating success if the string argument was successfully parsed to a `uint`, and it sets the `out` parameter to the parsed value on success:

```
public static bool IsUint32(string input)
{
    uint result;
    return uint.TryParse(input, out result);
}
```

Then you can use it in your code:

```
if (IsUint32(textBoxSN.Text))
{
    // Valid input was entered
}
```

In general, it's always better to avoid using exception handling (`try/catch`) for validation, because it's more expensive and leads to messy code.